# Trouble implementing contextual aware icon button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField and an IconButton in a row like so.

[image]

I would like the IconButton to be enabled only when there is text in the TextField. I am using the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for state management.

Here is the ChangeNotifier implementation.

```
class ChatMessagesProvider with ChangeNotifier{

List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = <ChatMessage>[];
bool messageTyped = false;

ChatMessagesProvider(this.chatMessages);

void newMessage(String textMessage){

ChatMessage message = ChatMessage(textMessage);

this.chatMessages.add(message);
notifyListeners();
}

int messageCount() => chatMessages.length;

void updateMessageTyped(bool typed){
this.messageTyped = typed;
//    notifyListeners(); Un-comennting this makes the Text disappear everytime I type something on the text field
}

}
```

Here is the actual widget:

```
class TextCompose extends StatelessWidget {

final TextEditingController _composeTextEditingController = new            TextEditingController();

TextCompose(this.chatMessagesProvider);

final ChatMessagesProvider chatMessagesProvider;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Container(
margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: Row(
children: <Widget>[
  Flexible(
    child: new TextField(
      controller: _composeTextEditingController,
      onSubmitted: (String text) {
        _onMessageSubmitted(text, context);
      },
      onChanged: (String text){
        if(text.length > 0){
          chatMessagesProvider.updateMessageTyped(true);
          print(text);
        }
        else{
          chatMessagesProvider.updateMessageTyped(false);
          print("No text typed");
        }
      },
      decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
          hintText: "Enter message"
      ),
    ),
  ),
  new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: new IconButton(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
      disabledColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed:chatMessagesProvider.messageTyped // This dosen't work
       ? () => _onMessageSubmitted(_composeTextEditingController.text, context)
       : null,
    ),
  )
],
),
);
}

void _onMessageSubmitted(String text, BuildContext context){
if(chatMessagesProvider.messageTyped) { // This works fine. 
// clear the message compose text box
_composeTextEditingController.clear();

// add the message to provider.
chatMessagesProvider.newMessage(text);

// set the message typed to false
chatMessagesProvider.messageTyped = false;
}
```

I am using messageTyped from ChatMessageProvider to check to see if there is any text in the TextField. It seems to work fine when I check it in the _onMessageSubmitted method but not when I check its value in the onPressed property for the IconButton.

I know this because I can see the IconButton remains disabled(colour doesn't change from grey) when I type text, whereas I can hit the submit button on the virtual keyboard and the text is cleared from the TextField(as per call to  _composeTextEditingController.clear())

Question:

- why does chatMessagesProvider.messageTyped return the right value when called from the _onMessageSubmitted but not when it is called from the onPrssed attribute in the IconButton?
- How would I debug something like this in Flutter, I would really like to drop a breakpoint in onPressedAttribute and see the value for chatMessagesProvider.messageTyped

Let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPressed:chatMessagesProvider.messageTyped` this line is being executed during widget build time so it is always default value and it will never get refreshed until unless you rebuild the widget using `notify listener` or stateful widget.

Store the `currently being typed message` in your `provider` and make your send button enable/disable depends on whether `currently being typed message` is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using 'provider_package' but you actually have no `Provider` in your layout. Instead you have a custom built `ChangeNotifier` with no listeners - you are indeed calling `notifyListeners()` but there are actually no listeners, so no rebuild is being triggered. A rebuild is needed in order for the button to change its `onPressed` function reference and implicitly its color.

As for debugging, you **can** set a breakpoint on the line with `onPressed`, but it will only be hit during a rebuild.

The most important thing to understand is that the function reference you give to `onPressed` will be invoked correctly, but a rebuild is needed for the widget to change visually.

Although your current `ChangeNotifier` implementation does not make much sense, simply wrapping your calls to `updateMessageTyped` within `setState` should solve the visual problem - and your breakpoint will also be hit after each typed/deleted character.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution you can, first of all, make your widget `StatefulWidget`.

You need a boolean inside `State` class:

```
bool hasText = false;
```

Then create `initState`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _composeTextEditingController.addListener(() {
      if (_composeTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          hasText = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          hasText = false;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Also don't forget to `dispose`:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _composeTextEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And finally your `build` method:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
        child: TextField(
      controller: _composeTextEditingController,
    )),
    if (hasText) IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.send), onPressed: () {})
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I was trying to use the provider package manage state.